# Postgresql - Update with result from CTE, sometimes CTE will have no output

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

In Postgresql (13) we are using UPDATE a table based on CTE results.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM some_other_table
)
UPDATE table_to_update
SET column_from_table_to_update = cte.some_column
FROM cte
WHERE table_to_update.date = cte.date
```

Sometimes, the CTE will not have any data i.e. empty. So in that case we don't want to run UPDATE (since no data to update). In fact I think the query is stuck or hang when such situation occurs.

How can I change the query, so it will update only if STE returns some data?

Comment: When there is no data to update, nothing will be updated. Not clear to my why you think the query is stuck, please update the question with information/proof for this

Comment: How is it different if the CTE has 1 or more rows of results, but none of those results match `table_to_update.date`? That would also cause the UPDATE to update no rows, but it would not hang; it would complete after changing no rows.

Comment: 1) In what client are you running this? 2) In `psql` you will probably get an error like: `... missing FROM-clause entry for table "cte".

Comment: Are you speculating about the query's behavior or reporting observed behavior? If the former, then create a test case to confirm or refute your theory. If the latter, then update the post with a [mre].